# Why doesn't this sed substitution for a non-ASCII byte work?

Tags: sed, character-encoding

I tried this substitution with GNU sed on OS X (4.2.2 installed through Homebrew). But it doesn't work.

```
printf "Hello\x92 World" | gsed -r "s/[\x92]/'/g"
```

The expected output is:

```
Hello' World
```

The actual output is:

```
Hello<unknown character symbol> World
```

I also tried:

```
printf "\x92" | gsed -r 's/[\x92]/P/g'
```

But I continue to get an unprintable character that is the byte '\x92'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try to do sed without brackets `[]`: `printf "\x92" | gsed -r 's/\x92/P/g'`

Comment: Yep, that works. I forgot to try that variation. I wonder why the escape `\x92` doesn't work inside `[]`.

Comment: Inside `[]` `\x92` treated as 4 chars list, which checked separately not altogether.

Comment: Then how would I include `\x92` as a member of the list `[]`? Is putting the byte literally the only way to go?

Comment: I don't have access to gnu sed right now, but would `gsed -r "s/["$'\x92'"]/'/g"` work?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked `sed`'s info page thoroughly (`info sed`) and done a fair bit of experimentation with various methods.

My conclusion: You can't get the character represented by `\x92` into a character class.

However, you can use `|` instead.

Here are some demonstrations:

```
$ printf "a\x92\n"
a?
$ printf "a\x92\n" | sed 's/[a\x92]/P/g'
P?
$ printf "a\x92\n" | sed 's/[a\\x92]/P/g'
P?
$ printf "a\x92\n" | sed 's/[a'$'\x92'']/P/g'
P?
$ printf "a\x92\n" | sed 's/[a'"$(printf '\x92')"']/P/g'
P?
$ printf "a\x92\n" | sed 's/[a[\x92]]/P/g'
a?
$ printf "a\x92\n" | sed 's/a\|\x92/P/g'
PP
$ printf "a\x92\n" | sed -r 's/a|\x92/P/g'
PP
$
```